# A question of mine was closed as being opinion based. I edited it to meet this objection. What would trigger a vote to reopen it?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287408/when-should-scripts-be-put-in-src-main-scripts-maven-standard-and-when-not) 8 months ago.  Someone recently upvoted it (making 4 over 8 months) but the question was recently closed as being "opinion-based".  I will agree that my title might have led someone to that conclusion, but the rest of the question and the comments were NOT in the nature of opinions.  I must say that it seems to me that the votes to close were based on "telling a book by its cover", but I recognize that people are busy.  Kind of like a Jeopardy answer being rejected because it wasn't posed in the form of a question.

Be the merits of this whatever they may, if the original poster of a question changes something to avoid the reason for closure, is there any automatic triggering of reconsideration on the part of those who voted to close it?  If not, what good is the advice to edit the question?

Comment: The edition triggers a vote

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: Congratulations on actually getting that eye-sore removed from the maven documentation by the way.

Comment: Hah!  I hadn't even realized that my bug report was answered!

Comment: Meh, you're also asking for tool recommendations which is specifically off topic.

Comment: There is no asking for tool recommendations in my question which you'd know if you took the time to read as opposed to skim it.  I did ask if there were any tools that made use of the "feature" in question, but that's not asking for a tool recommendation.  So here's what we have.  A post gets 4 upvotes.  It is referenced in a bug report to the Maven people, who agree with the bug report and remove the confusing documentation.  Meanwhile Stack Overflow closes the question as "opinion-based" based, I am guessing, on a title skim.  And then you pile on.  Not pretty.

Comment: @SteveCohen Will is actually a good person, cut him some slack. As to the question it is not opinion based at first glance, but I don't see how it can attract any kind of empirical answer. Its only going to attract guesses and opinions as to what the origin is of that weird directory. Mine: it is legacy from the Maven 1 days.

Comment: OK, I'll cut Will some slack.  I think it does point up a problem, though.  The people who have taken upon themselves the thankless task of culling through the questions looking for ones that may fall short of the ideal, perhaps inevitably get bleary-eyed, and perhaps, without even noticing it, resort to skimming, with sometimes bad results.  In this particular case, though, do note that my bug report actually resulted in the Maven folks removing this questionable documentation.  I would like to answer my own question to that effect, but I can't because the question has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing a post will trigger a reopen review for it, no further action is needed. Admittedly, I only saw it mentioned at the end of the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) description, so it may be hard to notice.