# Should the message in "on hold" dialog mention more about review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Sometimes I can see some users ask how to reopen a question (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323768/how-to-remove-on-hold-mark-after-editing) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309875/a-question-of-mine-was-closed-as-being-opinion-based-i-edited-it-to-meet-this-o)), and the current "on hold" dialog is something like:

> ...please edit the question.

But as a user, besides knowing editing the question, I would also like to know what happens after editing, such as: how do edits remove the "on hold"; how long do I wait to reopen it; and so on.

I think the "on hold" dialog can mention more about the review queue, such as:

> ...please edit the question. Once edited, the question will be placed in
>   a review queue (link to page about review queue mechanism and how it
>   works to reopen a question) where it can be reopened by the community.

Is that a good idea?

Comment: With formatting and grammar fixes applied, yes, it's a good idea.

Comment: I am not sure if it happens now but if this was done then the banner will need to be changed if the question moves from [on hold] to [closed] status(this happens 5 days after closure).  Once that happens an edit will no longer make the question enter the reopen vote queue.  Otherwise good proposal.

Comment: I just stumbled over this fact - it seems to me that on hold / close box should include a link to the vote that has been taken. My question [regarding the on-hold process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325547/) is getting downvoted right now. Part of it was me not beeing aware about the review process and some links (for example timeline).